# Getting error: Element type is invalid, when importing custom module

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Getting an error when importing a custom module: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object

```
import CustomButton from "custom-button";
```

Similar error when I add brackets: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

```
import { CustomButton } from "custom-button";
```

If I import from a specified path it works:

```
import CustomButton from "custom-button/build/index.js";
```

This is our package.json for the module

```
{
  "name": "custom-button",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "build/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack --watch --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "webpack": "^4.28.4",
    "webpack-command": "^0.4.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

***UPDATED*** webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'index.js',
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|build)/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "html-loader"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'url-loader',
                        options: {
                            limit: 8192
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    externals: {
        'react': 'commonjs react'
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you share your webpack config file?

Comment: Updated issue to include webpack.config.js